# Optimize a Function with Respect to a Set

Tags: probability, distributions, optimization, measure-theory, functional-data-analysis

Suppose I have some set of points $X = \{x_1,...,x_N\}, x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a measure $\mu$ (i.e. a probability distribution) defined with respect to those points. Specifically, if $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mu(A)$ is the probability that $x_i \in A$ given by

$$\mu(A) = \frac{\#(x_i \in A)}{N}$$

Consider a finite set of points $A \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and the set of $\epsilon$-balls of these points, $\mathcal{B}(A) = \{B(y, \epsilon) \mid y \in A\}$ such that all $B \in \mathcal{B}(A)$ are disjoint, i.e. $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset \ \forall \ i,j$.

Define the $q$-th moment of the measure over an $\epsilon$-ball at a point $y$,

$$M_q[\mu(B(y, \epsilon))]= \mu(B(y, \epsilon))^q$$

Now sum $M_q$ over the set of $\mathcal{B}(A)$ defined earlier,

$$\sum_{B \in \mathcal{B}(A)} M_q[\mu(B)]$$

Does there exist some set of algorithms that would allow me to efficiently maximize this sum with respect to $A$? In other words, is there a way to efficiently compute

$$M_q^* = \sup_A\sum_{B \in \mathcal{B}(A)} M_q[\mu(B)]$$

I have a feeling the answer is no, since the problem is somewhat related to Karp's set cover problem which is NP-Hard.

Comment: did you look at [GMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments)?

Comment: @Aksakal I don't think this problem satisfies a lot of the conditions for GMM. In particular, the function $M_q[\mu(B)]$ is not continuous or differentiable and does not satisfy the global identifiability condition or even its weaker counterparts.

Comment: Is there limit on $A$ beside being finite? Otherwise we can take $A = X + \{\epsilon/n, \ldots, (n-1) \epsilon/n\}$, which imply $\sum_{B \in \mathcal{B}(A)} M_{q}[\mu(B)] = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{x \in X} M_{q}[\mu(B(x + i \epsilon /n, \epsilon))] \ge (n-1) / N^q$, and therefore the supremum is infinity.

Comment: @tmrlvi Good catch, I forgot to say that the $B \in \mathcal{B}$ should be disjoint. I'll edit the question.